# Getting the dreaded "Iterator cannot be used nested" exception

Tags: libgdx

Getting this exception randomly in my 3D game (using libgdx nightly build from 2014-01-03). Sometimes none for days, sometimes 5 times in 10 minutes. Almost never happens on emulator. Haven't found any reproducible scenario for weeks now, can happen even when I'm not touching the tablet at all. (I had a feeling that moving the camera or touching the screen causes this with higher probability but couldn't prove it.) Usually happens when a long worker thread (computer 'thinking', continuous rendering is turned off during this) is finished and some of the models are being repositioned to show the results.

Happens always on the same model instance consisting of 100 nodes (each node is a textured box created by six `rect()` calls). Some nodes may be in a short animation. I'm not requesting an iterator anywhere in my own code, I walk through the nodes with a normal `for()` loop because their number is fixed.

Any suggestions on how to start investigating this are appreciated. The only clue I might have that when I had the above boxes as 100 different model instances, the exception occurred somewhat less frequently. Today I merged them into one large model and already got the exception 10 times.

```
E/AndroidRuntime(30999): com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: #iterator() cannot be used nested.
E/AndroidRuntime(30999):    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array$ArrayIterator.hasNext(Array.java:487)
E/AndroidRuntime(30999):    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.ModelInstance.getRenderables(ModelInstance.java:356)
E/AndroidRuntime(30999):    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.ModelInstance.getRenderables(ModelInstance.java:328)
E/AndroidRuntime(30999):    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.ModelBatch.render(ModelBatch.java:281)
E/AndroidRuntime(30999):    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.ModelBatch.render(ModelBatch.java:296)
```

Comment: Without any code, it is a bit difficult to help you... By reading the libgdx code, it can only happen when you use `Array.iterator()` twice in a row and then try to use the first iterator.

Comment: Yes, I understand it's hard to help me, I'll post code if I get at least a little closer. My newest suspicion is that I'm calling some libgdx method that uses the iterator from outside the rendering thread and it clashes with the rendering.

Comment: Maybe you render the same model twice?

Comment: Nope, I was right about the thread problem, added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it was a threading problem. Most of my models are manipulated via AnimationController, but there was one place where a direct move was issued from another thread:

```
modelInstanceTiles.nodes.get(nodeIndex).translation.set(pos);
modelInstanceTiles.nodes.get(nodeIndex).rotation.set(rot);
modelInstanceTiles.calculateTransforms();
```

I have changed this to a very fast animation and no exception for 3 days now.